# How to add a span tag in Ckeditor?

Tags: html, ckeditor

I'm trying to add a span with a custom style in CKeditor:

```
{name: "Tag", element: ['span'], attributes: { class:"tag-name" }}
```

Now, how can i insert a span in my text? There is no button for a span i think?

I tried to put the span tag in the format_tags section:

```
format_tags: p;h1;h2;h3;h4;h5;h6;div;span
```

But it doesn't work.

Is there any solution?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

Ok i found a solution

```
format_tags: p;h1;h2;h3;h4;h5;h6;div;span
format_span: { name : 'Span', element : 'span'}
```

And i obtain a Span in the format selectbox